# Testing angular factory

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying hard to bring up the unit test level of an Angular project but struggling to test an AngularJS factory that has dependencies.

My factory has 5 dependencies but I can't even get a test working that just tests that the factory is defined. Here is some sample code of what I'm doing. I have tried using inject, $provide ect but I keep getting an error along the lines of

```
"Configuration parameter should be an object, instead it is a: undefined"
```

Here's the test, so far, I've left commented out code in to show what I've been trying:

```
(function() {

'use strict';

 describe('While working with the channelService', function(){

var sut,
    q,
    filter,
    common,
    dataContext,
    etCommon;

beforeEach(function(){

  // Load the module
   module('app');
   module('app.inventory');
   module('blocks.router');

  inject(function($injector){
    sut = $injector.get('channelService');
    q = $injector.get('$q');
    filter = $injector.get('$filter');
    common = $injector.get('common');
    dataContext = $injector.get('dataContext');
    etCommon = $injector.get('etCommons');

    spyOn(q, 'defer');
    spyOn(filter  , 'defer');
    spyOn(common, 'makeStruct');
    spyOn(q, 'defer');
    spyOn(q, 'defer');
  });




describe('should define the following publicly', function(){
  it('should be defined itself', function(){
      expect(sut).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

});

})();

SErvice is along the lines of

```
(function () {

angular.module('app.inventory').factory('channelService', [
    '$q', '$filter', 'common', 'dataContext', 'etCommon',
    function ($q, $filter, common, dataContext, etCommon) {
...

...
]);

}());
```

Comment: Post your service definition, remove all the commented out code from your question, and post the complete and exact error message.

Comment: In your test, you get `etCommons` from the injector. But the service is named `etCommon`. BTW, why use the injector, and not simply inject the services in the test directly? `inject(function(channelService, $q, $filter, ...) {`

Comment: If I just inject the actual service, I should at least be able to expect it to be defined though shouldn't I? without mocking all the dependencies

beforeEach(inject(function(channelService) {
                sut = channelService;
        }));

Answer (score 0):

Try using ngMock in your beforeEach

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock
```